# Handled exception in Controller can not call error function in ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

If I handle A exception In Controller how ajax will Know that Exception Is Occured So That I Can Call Error Function in Ajax To Solve My Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return an error status code.

You could allow the framework to do it for you by simply rethrowing the exception:

```
try
{
 //
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw;
}
```

Another option is for your response to include an error status code.

That will trigger the error function in your ajax call.

Comment: I can not re throw the exception .

Comment: How do i add error status code in my response .i am returning a partial view in success function data for appending it to My Main view.Please Help I am Stuck